# Is it safe to expose a port opened from netcat?

Tags: linux, networking, netcat

I'm planning to open a port from a device inside my LAN to the internet with the command:

```
nc -kl 9999 > /dev/null
```

The idea is just to know if that specific device is powered on whenever I want to check (can't do it with ICMP's forwarding due to limitations on my home router).

However I'm not sure if netcat is prone to DDoS attacks or some other kind of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Should be fine for a brief period of time. The only risk is when it’s an extended period of time.

Comment: If it is visible on the internet - it will be found. What will happen to it when it is found... is a completely different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, yes, though maybe not entirely.

By default, netcat does not process received data at all – all it does is write the data to stdout – so there are no exploits that could be used against it.

(Assuming it properly reuses the buffers and doesn't leak memory, that is – but that's easy to verify experimentally; pipe a few GB through netcat and see if its memory usage grows. For such a simple tool, it really shouldn't be the case.)

Since netcat is TCP-based, it can't become any more of a DDoS "reflector" than any other TCP service.

Netcat (your version at least) only processes one connection at a time, so while one host *might* flood you with an infinite data stream and waste your CPU resources, that's limited to one host so isn't exactly a "distributed" DoS.

Though on the other hand, since netcat only processes one connection at a time (and lets the OS pre-accept and buffer a *limited* number of connections), if you're suddenly receiving a large amount of "bot" connections, your own remote checks might start failing when the number of "pending" connection slots is exhausted. Consider using an even higher port number (from the transient range) to reduce the chance of bots finding it.